# Regexp Return position VBA

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I am looking to have my regexp return the value of of the pattern I am looking for or the position. Similar to how the Instr function works returning its position in a string I would like to be able to do this with patterns. what i have so far just replaces the patters and i cannot figure out how to have it return a position.

```
Sub test

Dim regex As Object
Dim r As Range, rC As Range
Dim firstextract As Long
' cells in column A
Set r = Range("A2:A3")
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regex.Pattern = "[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

' loop through the cells in column A and execute regex replace
Dim MyArray(10, 10) As Integer

For CntMtg = 1 To 100
For Each rC In r
    If rC.Value <> "" Then rC.Value = regex.Replace(rC.Value, "Extract from here")
Next rC
Next
End sub
```

Comment: @FunThomas i am having a problem with this code finding a match it is saying match is "nothing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to replace but just get the position of a hit, use the `Execute`-method. It returns a Collection of Matches. A match has basically three properties:
`FirstIndex` is the position of the match within your string
`Length` is the length of the match that was found
`Value` it the match itself that was found

If you can have more than one match within a string, you need to set the property `Global` of your regex, else the collection will at most find 1 hit.

The following code uses early binding (as it helps to figure out properties and methods), add a reference to *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5*.

```
Dim regex As RegExp
regex.Pattern = "[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
regex.Global = True
    
Dim matches As MatchCollection, match As match
Set matches = regex.Execute(s)
For Each match In matches
    Debug.Print "Pos: " & match.FirstIndex & "  Len: " & match.Length & "  - Found: " & match.Value
Next
```

For details, see the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/the-regular-expression-object-model

Comment: I am having an issue with Match being empty in this code so it is skipping the for loop

Comment: My code is just an example - you will have to replace the `Execute(s)` with something like `Execute(rC.Value)` so that the content of the cell is handled.

Comment: thank you very much i was able to get it to work using your code